# remove a tuple from python list:The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a python list that contains different elements including tuples:

```
RList =
['2018-05-28', 'STRL', 100000, 20000, (20000, 0.0185), (40000, 0.0174), (60000, 
0.0169), (1000000, 0.0165)]
```

when I want to remove one of the tuples:

```
RList.remove((20000, 0.0185))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't understand why I should get this error.

Comment: That looks like a numpy error. I can't reproduce it with the plain list presented.

Comment: Sounds like `RList` is actually a numpy array or the like, not a `list`.  Is it?

Comment: Tried to reproduce the error but as the other guys stated, this does not happen with normal python lists

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you probably have a numpy Array (or pandas Series) not a list.

This should work:

```
RList = RList[RList != (20000, 0.0185)]
```

or convert it to a list:

```
RList = list(RList)
```